# Close Modal when click outside

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use javascript to get my modal to close when you click outside but it doesn't seem to be working, can anybody help?

```
var clickHandler = function () {
    if (!f.target) f.target = f.srcElement;
    if (f.target.tagName == "DIV") {
        if (f.target.id != "window") closeModal(f);
}
```

Tried the above but no luck, any clues?

Comment: Where is `f` from?

Comment: did you forget to pass the `f` ?


```var clickHandler = function (f) {```